# How do I expand my axes in matplotlib plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My graph originally looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the words to be visible and for there to be more space between the axes.

How would I do that in matplotlib?

```
# np.zeros_like(semantic_projection_scores)
plt.scatter(movement_speed_scores, np.zeros_like(movement_speed_scores), s = 10, color = "blue")
for i, txt in enumerate(movement_list):
    plt.annotate(txt, (movement_speed_scores[i], np.zeros_like(movement_speed_scores)[i]))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=spacing)
# delete y axis
plt.yticks([])
# spread x axis
```

Attached is my code. Please assist!